# iOS app crashing if data is inaccessible

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I'm using the following to request data using `NSJSONSerialization`. The problem I'm having is that if the data is inaccessible (e.g. no network connection) the app crashes. How could I go about stopping the app from crashing if the network or server is down?

I'm calling `[self requestData];` in the `viewDidLoad:` method

```
-(void)requestData {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                          URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/nodes"]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

    NSDictionary *publicData =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                options:0
                                                                  error:&jsonParsingError];
    publicDataArray = [publicData objectForKey:@"data"];
    for(publicDataDict in publicDataArray) {
        NSLog(@"data output is %@",[publicDataDict objectForKey:@"title"]);

    }
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: try to add try/catch block

Comment: It would be better to make sure your response object is valid before trying to parse it as if was json. It would be even better to use an asynchronous request and checking if there is a network connection available.

Comment: try & catch u dnt want your app to crash if server is down

Comment: try/catch for program flow is contrary to Cocoa Practice. It's usually reserved for programmer errors. Using the provided error parameters and return values is how you control program flow.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't know what error would be catchable here.  It seems like the app would be killed by the watchdog for tying up the main thread for too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you check if `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:]` got any error?

```
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&requestError];

if (requestError)
{
    NSLog(@"sync. request failed with error: %@", requestError);
}
else
{
    // handle data
}
```

And you really should check if `NSJSONSerialization` had an error too:

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

NSDictionary *publicData =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                            options:0
                                                              error:&jsonParsingError];
if (jsonParsingError)
{
    NSLog(@"JSON parsing failed with error: %@", jsonParsingError);
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but here's the thing. The error parameter is only _guaranteed_ to be valid if the method returns nil. It's far better practice to check if the return from the method is nil before querying the error parameter.

Comment: This is detailed in the [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) search for the section titled "Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods" and then look at the "Important" block after listing 2-1.

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts:

1. Use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) for checking network connection
2. Always use asynchronous request, else it'll block your UI till the app get the response from server.
3. Always use exception handling

Here the issue is:

You are calling a `synchronous` request in the `viewDidLoad` using `sendSynchronousRequest`. But the server is down, so you won't get the result, and it still expect any data to come. But your app won't load untill that request finishes. Due to this springboards application-watchdog will terminate your app.

**What is Watch dog** ?

> watchdog — In order to keep the user interface responsive, iOS
>   includes a watchdog mechanism. If your application fails to respond to
>   certain user interface events (launch, suspend, resume, terminate) in
>   time, the watchdog will kill your application and generate a watchdog
>   timeout crash report. The amount of time the watchdog gives you is not
>   formally documented, but it's always less than a network timeout.

Please check this [Technical question](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1693/_index.html) on Apple site.

Comment: 3. Is debatable, also 4. Put a timeout on your URL request, if you haven't already. (+1)